# how to scrape media from Linkedin?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

The goal is to scrape a posts caption and the image link or an article link or a video link but some of the post don't have any media

When I am trying to scrape an image the it is printing 'None' instead of the link. I am not able to get around the idea of how to loop through and get links for those with media and print nothing for those without media.

```
def profile():
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrewyng/detail/recent-activity/shares/"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('occludable-update.ember-view')
    for post in posts:
        caption = post.find_element_by_class_name('break-words').text
        print(caption.strip())

        time.sleep(5)
        img_tag = post.find_element_by_class_name('ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper.ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag.display-flex')
        img_link = img_tag.get_attribute("src")
        print(img_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you locator

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('occludable-update.ember-view')
```

is wrong. Try this instead

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.occludable-update.ember-view')
```

The same about `img_tag` element. Try this Xpath instead `.//img[contains(@class,'image__image')]`
So your code can be something like this:

```
def profile():
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrewyng/detail/recent-activity/shares/"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"occludable-update ember-view")]')

    for post in posts:
        caption = post.find_element_by_class_name('break-words').text
        print(caption.strip())

        time.sleep(5)
        img_tag = post.find_element_by_xpath(".//img[contains(@class,'image__image')]")
        img_link = img_tag.get_attribute("src")
        print(img_link)
```

I would also advise using explicit wait instead of hardcoded sleeps and not use locators inside the code.
This will bring your code look like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
def profile():
    posts_xpath_locator = '//*[contains(@class,"occludable-update ember-view")]'
    post_img_xpath = './/img[contains(@class,"image__image")]'
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrewyng/detail/recent-activity/shares/"
    driver.get(url)

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, posts_xpath_locator)))
    time.sleep(0.1) #just a small delay to make all posts loaded
    posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(posts_xpath_locator)

    for post in posts:
        caption = post.find_element_by_class_name('break-words').text
        print(caption.strip())

        time.sleep(5)
        img_tag = post.find_element_by_xpath(post_img_xpath)
        img_link = img_tag.get_attribute("src")
        print(img_link)
```

Comment: The changes that you suggested give this error selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: for what locator?

Comment: posts_css_locator

Comment: the xpath is printing the samelink for every post which happend with me the first time i used xpath

Comment: Hm.. i have added `.` in XPath, it should fix that problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233618/discussion-between-grasper-and-prophet).